# After dismiss modal menu and setRoot() not working perfectly in IONIC 3 . Any solution?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, modalviewcontroller

> I am using below code for showing modal from HomePage

```
import { SignaturePage } from '../signature/signature'
import { NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})

export class QuotationPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalController:ModalController) {
      this.signatureImage = navParams.get('signatureImage');
  }
   //By approve button click this modal will appear
   approvebtn(){
     let modal = this.modalController.create(SignaturePage,{
        "text": "something"
     });
     modal.present();
   }
}
```

> TS code for modal page. 
>   When I am trying to set home page as a root page then navigation is not working and setRoot function is not working for set root page.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SignaturePad} from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signature',
  templateUrl: 'signature.html',
})
export class SignaturePage {
  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) public signaturePad : SignaturePad;
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController;

  quotetext:any = "";
  public signaturePadOptions : Object = {
    'minWidth': 2,
    'canvasWidth': 320,
    'canvasHeight': 348
  };
  public signatureImage : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParam:NavParams, public viewCtrl:ViewController) {
  }

  drawCancel() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

> here is the transition function

```
   drawComplete() {
    this.signatureImage = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
       this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }

  drawClear() {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }

}
```

Comment: Home page is your root page right?

Comment: For my app homepage is DashboardPage then -> SomePage->SignaturePage-> by call drawcomplete it comes again to DashboardPage but menu not working and when I am clicking device backbutton twice it comes to SomePage.

Answer (score 3):

When you navigating from an `Overlay` Component you need to do as shown below.

```
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController,private appCtrl: App) {}

drawComplete() {
    this.signatureImage = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);
  }
```

You can read more about [**this here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BztyVw_3LTvlNElFRmpEYVV6aXc

Check this apk then you would understand this problem.

Register(just hit the button) -> From dashboard select any -> select any product -> now contact renewal -> signature

Comment: You can play it from your device

Comment: How can debug it then?

Comment: Really thank you, you saved my day. How did you learn this? I'm searching at the docs and I can't find any text about this.

Comment: It is here @manuman94 https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component

Comment: Thank you so much. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

You can pop all pages which are pushed using `popToRoot()`

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
```

Comment: Not working for me because I want to move forward to root

Comment: Have you tried that? Because there is this way to set Dashboard Page as root

Comment: Yes I have tried. but I have another two pages before modal and after modal one page. so i want to move forward from last page.

Comment: Can i move upto root index by popAll()?

Comment: Yes you can. popAll() reach you at top of stack of page

Comment: What is happening when you use that?

Comment: it popping just previous page